# mongoid.yml sets wrong database in production

Tags: mongoid

I upgraded to mongoid 3.0.1 and created the new format of mongoid.yml - my mongoid.yml looks like this :

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: grbr_production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: grbr_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        raise_not_found_error: false
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: grbr_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        raise_not_found_error: false
```

in development, I see correct db getting picked. but in production I see that "admin" database is getting picked and that breaks my app. I have set RAILS_ENV to "production" in my production machine but still I see this error. Another very strange thing I see is that in production, moped does not even query the database.
The following logs from development and production shows that :

```
Development log:
 MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.6645ms)**
 MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=grbr_development collection=topsearches  selector={"$query"=>{"type"=>"books"}, "$orderby"=>{"cnt"=>-1}} flags=[] limit=10 skip=0 fields=nil (0.8984ms)

Production Log:
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.6878ms)**
```

so in production, I can not see the queries getting fired on the production db.

Comment: Hey @Ved any luck with this issue? I'm having a similar issue and can't figure it out...

Comment: any luck on this? I have simulated and it works all fine for me, I believe could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your production pointing to localhost? That seems off.

You might try something like this:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: "YOUR-DB-ADDRESS"
```